# Is it possible to create uninterned symbols in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

Answer to [What is the difference between an “interned” and an “uninterned” symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8855887/387194)
 explain what is the difference between those symbols. My questions is can those symbols be created in Scheme as per R7RS spec?

I've tested this in Guile:

```lisp
scheme@(guile-user)> (eq? (string->symbol "foo") (string->symbol "foo"))
$1 = #t
```

so `string->symbol` created interned symbol because eq? return `#t`, is there other way to create uninterned symbols or maybe gensym just create this type of symbols? In LIPS, my [Scheme implementation in JavaScript](https://lips.js.org/) I use JavaScript symbols as names (for gensyms) and strings for normal symbols, but I don't intern them (I have task to do that), in my case eq? just check if type of value is LSymbol and check the names that are strings or JavaScript Symbols, so gensyms are never the same because Symbols created without `Symbol.for` are never the same.

I was wondering, Is it enough to intern every symbols (keep only one instance per value) and that gensym don't do that, to have this system that would work correctly as per R7RS spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not portably, no.  [R7RS-small](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf) has this to say:

> Note: Some implementations have values known as "uninterned symbols," which defeat write/read invariance, and also violate the rule that two  symbols  are  the same if and only if their names are spelled the same.  This report does not specify the behavior of implementation-dependent extensions.

I have no idea what the plans are for R7RS-large.